# odoo[1179109]: ValueError: Module mail not loaded or inexistent

Tags: linux, runtime-error, odoo, syslog

My odoo was installed using the below URL.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-odoo-on-ubuntu-20-04/

After creating users below is the URL for odoo login.

http://erp.digiklug.com:8069/web/login

Getting the below error in `/var/log/syslog` after i login

> Jan  5 14:48:08 ERPDK odoo[1179109]: ValueError: Module mail not loaded or inexistent, or templates of addon being loaded (hr_holidays) are misordered - - -

Below is my Linux version:

```
root@ERPDK:~# uname -a
Linux ERPDK 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Due to this error, the next page does not show after the login button is clicked.

Comment: Can you provide the .py file (or the relevant class) of the hr_holidays model? Is this your own model or an open source one? If open source, just check it's the right version for your odoo instance.

Comment: @Luke open source one